# How do I fix an Invalid Expression Term '=' error in Unity/C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Heyo, not very familiar with C#, much less Unity, and I'm apparently doing something wrong, here's my code, THe only error I get is:

> 'Invalid Expression Term "="'

```
    bool currentlydown;
// further up the script
void Start() {
        currentlydown = false;
    }
// later up the script
void Update() {
if ((Input.GetKeyDown("W") || Input.GetKeyDown("A") || Input.GetKeyDown("S") || Input.GetKeyDown("D")) && currentlydown === false) {
            anim.SetBool("Walking", true);
            currentlydown = true;
        } else if (!(Input.GetKeyDown("W") || Input.GetKeyDown("A") || Input.GetKeyDown("S") || Input.GetKeyDown("D")) && currentlydown === true){
            anim.SetBool("Walking", false);
            currentlydown = false;
        }
    }
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You're using `===` (I assume from JavaScript?). C# does not have a `===` operator, only `==`.
- JavaScript has `===` in order to require that the types of the operands are also strictly the same. C# is statically-typed and most types are not directly comparable so a `===` operator isn't necessary.
- Also, when comparing reference-types (`object`, `string`, etc) the `==` operator (by default) only checks that both operands (which are references) point to the same single object in memory (almost-but-not-quite a pointer-comparison) which necessarily implies the types *are* identical, even if cast to different reference-types:

  ```
  interface IFoobar {}
  class Foobar : IFoobar {};

  Foobar  a = new Foobar();
  Object  b = a;
  IFoobar c = a;

  // Even though `a` and `b` have different reference-types (`Object` vs `IFoobar`) they point to the same object in-memory, so a type-check is unnecessary.
  Console.WriteLine( b == c ); // "true"

  // Whereas with value-types you'll get a compiler error:
  Int32 x = 123;
  String y = "abc";

  Console.WriteLine( x == y ); // <-- This won't compile because Int32 and String cannot be compared.
  ```
- So change your code to use `==`.
- You can also simplify your logic and make your code more readable by moving the `Input.GetKeyDown()` checks and storing that in a local `bool isWasd`.

Like so:

```
bool currentlydown;
// further up the script
void Start()
{
    currentlydown = false;
}

// later up the script
void Update() {

    bool isWasd = Input.GetKeyDown("W")
            ||
            Input.GetKeyDown("A")
            ||
            Input.GetKeyDown("S")
            ||
            Input.GetKeyDown("D");

    if( isWasd && currentlydown == false )
    {
        anim.SetBool("Walking", true);
        currentlydown = true;
    }
    else if ( !(isWasd) && currentlydown == true ){
        anim.SetBool("Walking", false);
        currentlydown = false;
    }
}
```

- When working with `bool` (`System.Boolean`) values, you don't need do `if( boolValue == true )` or `if( !(boolValue == true) )` or `if( boolValue == false )`, you can do `if( boolValue )` and `if( !boolValue )`.

Like so:

```
// later up the script
void Update()
{
    bool isWasd =
        Input.GetKeyDown("W")
        ||
        Input.GetKeyDown("A")
        ||
        Input.GetKeyDown("S")
        ||
        Input.GetKeyDown("D");

    if( isWasd && !currentlydown)
    {
        anim.SetBool("Walking", true);
        currentlydown = true;
    }
    else if( !isWasd && currentlydown )
    {
        anim.SetBool("Walking", false);
        currentlydown = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was confused on why it wouldn't set the bool, I thought with C# it had used '===', think that's from when I was making my discord bot, much obliged.